# How can I read from a specific position in a file

Tags: vb.net

Right now I'm trying to check if the pass is right when reading the file, but the problem is I have a "`Pass:`" String in front of the pass.

```
writeFile.WriteLine("Pass: " + Me.txtCPass.Text) ' pass
Me.txtPassword.Text = (GetLine(FILE_NAME, 2))
```

Not sure how I would just skip over the "Pass: " and just get right to the pass.

Comment: `Substring()` is what you're looking for. [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=VS.71).aspx)

Comment: Could you possibly add a little more? That doesn't help at all.

Comment: All right, added an answer

Comment: Thanks, Steve! Finally got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that GetLine returns a string then

```
Me.txtPassword.Text = GetLine(FILE_NAME, 2).Substring(6)
```

Substring is a method of the string class. It returns part of the string instance for which is called.
You could pass a starting index and the method returns the remainder.
Or you could also pass a length to force the method to return a defined part inside the instance

[Here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) you could find a detailed description

Answer (score 0):

Me.txtPassword.Text = GetLine(FILE_NAME, 2).Substring(6)